# What's a word that means "we fix things without you noticing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means "we fix things without you noticing"?

In a business context, an example would be where a company's technology works in the background so if their API changes or the site changes, work continues as we fix the problem or integration.

Answer (score 2):

**seamless**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/seamless)

> without noticeable change from one part to the next

As in:

*We seamlessly fix things without you noticing.*

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the audience, "transparently" might be appropriate, as in this Q&A:

> Some devops heavyweights release software updates thousands of times per day — often so transparently that their users are not even aware.

[Word for "a change not noticable, transparent to users"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458013/word-for-a-change-not-noticable-transparent-to-users)

Answer (score 0):

You might be Heinzelmännchen (although i do not know whether the common english substitute terms ('brownies', 'elves', 'trolls', 'fairies', 'leprechauns', 'house gnomes') have the same virtue of being both unanimously benign and unladen with unintended meaning and imagery as the original term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinzelm%C3%A4nnchen